# ag-grid api remove event listener

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ag-grid

When trying to move from a grid component to another screen, an error occurs in the status panel component.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'useAsyncEvents')
at GridApi.removeEventListener

```
export const TotalRowsGridStatusPanel = (props: IStatusPanelParams) => {

    const [countRows] = useCounterRows(props.api)

    return (<Box>Rows:<Space /><Box component={"span"}>{countRows}</Box></Box>)
}

export const useCounterRows = (gridApi: GridApi) => {
    const cleanupFunctionRef = useRef(false)
    const [countRows, setCountRows] = useState<number | null>(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        cleanupFunctionRef.current = false

        function setRows() {
            if (cleanupFunctionRef.current) return
            setCountRows(getValueOrNull(FinanceUtils.getRowCount(gridApi)))
        }

        gridApi.addEventListener('modelUpdated', setRows)

        return () => {
            cleanupFunctionRef.current = true
            if (!gridApi) return
            gridApi.removeEventListener('modelUpdated', setRows)

        }
    }, [gridApi])

    return [countRows]
}
```